# Number of lags for a unit root test

Tags: dataset, panel-data, unit-root

I have some panel data and am suspicious of presence of unit root. As the dataset is unbalanced, I would like to use the `xtunitroot fisher` command in Stata. Is there any way to find out the optimal number of lags? The `dfgls` command for time series data provides multiple criteria for optimal lag selection, is there any similar approach also for panel data? When only one lag is included, the null is rejected on a low significance level but when the number of lags increases, the result is diametrically different.

Answer (score 1):

`xtunitroot fisher` does nothing but combining the $p$-values of individual unit root tests via 
$$-2\sum_i\ln(p_i).$$ 
So if you are concerned that you need different lag lengths for the different series in the panel, you can construct $p$-values for each time series test via `dfgls` and easily combine these using the above formaula.